# What is the purpose of flux lines in quantum circuits?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, quantum-information, quantum-electrodynamics, cavity-qed

I have come across flux lines that are being used to tune the frequency of transmon qubits in circuit QED.
I do not understand it on the hardware level. Is it related to magnetic flux being passed through those flux lines to tune the frequency of the qubits?